# Flink Streaming JdbcSink Exception Handling

Tags: jdbc, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using JdbcSink to insert processed events into a Postgres DB.

Occasionally, I receive bad records from the source stream, and it fails to insert into the database (`java.sql.BatchUpdateException`) since it fails to satisfy some table constraints.

I can obviously pass the events through a Flink filter operator to filter them, but the filter would then become a complex code to check every possible combination of failure. Instead of a filter, I would like to catch the BatchUpdateException thrown by the JdbcSink, log it and continue processing other events.

No luck trying to find a way to catch BatchUpdateException from JdbcSink.
Has someone tried doing similar with success?

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the code, and didn't see an obvious solution. You could extend the `JdbcOutputFormat` class and override the `attemptFlush` method, and then clone the `JdbcSink` class and modify your version to use your output format class.

Comment: Hi @kkrugler, tried overriding the method, but the failed statement is still getting retried at every batch interval. I had also tried to invoke the close() method from the catch block, present in the JdbcOutputFormat class to stop it from getting retried everytime but that had a problem that the next bacth of records were not getting inserted into the table. Here's the sample code.

Comment: @Override
    protected void attemptFlush() {
        try {
            super.attemptFlush();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            super.close();
            try {
                super.open(5,8);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Why are you doing a `super.close()` and then `super.open()`?

Comment: If I just catch the exception and do nothing, the failed statements are getting retried every batch interval. So I had to call the close function to stop this from happening.

Comment: I believe the issue is that `jdbcStatementExecutor` still has the pending requests in it. Perhaps calling `updateExecutor(true)` would close/re-prepare it?

Comment: That doesn't work, it still retries the failed statement continuously. :(